# Intergrate webcam in website

Tags: silverlight, flash

i need a "take picture" option in my website which is developed in MVC3 and C# where i can capture image from web cam on clients pc and want to store that image on my server in some specific folder.

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can achive that using flash and Camera code. I suggest you use http://www.kevinmusselman.com/2009/02/access-webcam-with-flash/

Regards
Vipin

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using the Microsoft stack and C# for everything you can use a small Silverlight application on the page to capture the current web-cam image.

e.g. You could make the whole Silverlight app just a single push button, if you wanted, to make it unobstrusive.

Take a look at this link "[Capturing the Webcam in Silverlight 4](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Capturing-the-Webcam-in-Silverlight-4.aspx)"